# Open PDF in Ibooks without the popUp

Tags: iphone, pdf

I am opening pdf documents from my application in Ibooks using

```
docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url]; //url is the file url saved inside my application.
docController.delegate = self;
[docController retain];
BOOL isValid = [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:NO];
```

I get a popup which says that Open In and in the options give all the available options to open the pdf.Is there any way to open it directly without having the pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this without breaking apples guidelines